# Having Javascript logic issues..again

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this line of code to test 2 conditions

```
if (
micStock[k].splice(0,2).join(" ")) == actMic[actMicMod] 
&& micStock[k][micStkAka] == actMic[actMicAka]
)
```

I need them to both be true to continue but for some reason it doesn't work. If I test each one individually they are true but when tested together with `&&` its false.

Very confused. Help Please!

Comment: You have a syntax error. An extra `)` after `join(" ")`.

Comment: splice modifies the array. You may want slice instead, since splice could be changing the value of `micStock[k][micStkAka]`.

Comment: That's got it @PaulPro. Didn't know that. Will need to read up. The extra bracket was just a typo whilst I formatted it for the here BTW. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.splice(0,2)` remove first 2 elements from array `micStock[k]` this is probably not desired behaviour

In Your code is also something wrong (I break line differently tan you to show it)

```
if ( micStock[k].splice(0,2).join(" ") )
   == actMic[actMicMod] 
   && micStock[k][micStkAka] == actMic[actMicAka] )
```

on first line end you have  extra `)`

Comment: You are absolutely correct as @PaulPro pointed out as well. `Splice` was wrong. Feel a bit dumb! Thanks guys. Helping the learners as ever!